# In Google Sheets how can I write a sequence with static words in front and a static number in back?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

so I am very ameature in google sheets.  I am an artist and I am organizing stock.  In google sheets I have title, price, medium, sold/not sold, etc...   I have print series that go up to 100.  for example "hummingbird 1/100" then the next row is
"hummingbird 2/100"  the next is
"hummingbird 3/100"  and I am trying to create a sequence so I don't have to type it out every row.  help please, thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

If you need exactly the value, the string "hummingbird 12/100", then a formula like

`="hummingbird " & (ROW()-2) & "/100"`

(In this case, **2** is the row number before the start of the list)

[image: Formula]

If you just want **to see** such a line, then use the [**cell formatting capabilities**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?visit_id=637977066156791811-3170449231&p=drive_custom_numbers&rd=1#zippy=%2Ccustom-number-formatting) - fill the cells with only serial numbers 1,2,3 and so on and then apply a custom number format `"hummingbird "0"/100"` to them

[image: Custom format]

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This formula does not need to be dragged down :

```
=index("hummingbird " & sequence(100) & "/100")
```

You will be able to place that formula in any cell of your sheet, as long as there are 99 other free cells below.

Comment: Thank you so much